# python sphinx auto documenting constants

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a bunch of non documented constants in my generated python module using SWIG. If I use pydoc I can get all these constants to be displayed, all I want is to list them out (obviously I don't want to type them manually). If they have a docstring below them they get documented, but otherwise they don't get taken. I'm trying to use autodoc like this:

```
.. automodule:: mymodule
```

I've also tried autodata but that requires me to list my constants and in either case then gives me the doc text for number which is obviously not useful.

Comment: There is no directive called `autodoc`. I suppose you mean `automodule`.

Comment: Of course - sorry I got confused! fixed in Q

Comment: Further down you write "I've generally settled on using autoclass instead of autodoc", which does not make sense. And if the question is about module-level constants, why do you mention "autoclass"?

Comment: Ignore that bit - that's really a seperate question and generally managed to hack my way out of that one already :)